# Azure Active Directory/Ldap use inside web-app

Tags: azure, active-directory, ldap, azure-web-app-service

We are currently testing azure web-app functionality for our own apache application. The application works with non security, but the application itself needs direct active directory access via ldap.

Example settings inside the application:

```
<ldap>
<connectionUrl>wehavenoidea:389</connectionUrl>
<roleBase>OU=AADDC Users,DC=ourdomain,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com</roleBase>
<userPattern>{0},OU=AADDC Users,DC=ourdomain,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com</userPattern>
<roleSearch>member={0}</roleSearch>
<useIndirectLookup>1</useIndirectLookup>
<indirectAdminDN>CN=AdminUser,OU=AADDC Users,DC=ourdomain,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com</indirectAdminDN>
<indirectAdminPassword>ourpassword</indirectAdminPassword>
<indirectUserBase>DC=ourdomain,DC=onmicrosoft,DC=com</indirectUserBase>
<indirectSearchFilter>sAMAccountName={0}</indirectSearchFilter>
<rolemap>
  <role target="Admin">Admin</role>
  <role target="Accounting">Accounting</role>
</rolemap>
</ldap>
```

I have set up the app registration inside azure active directory with the required permissions. I can't find the connection url for the AD though.

Does anybody here know how to set this up?

Kind regards

Comment: AAD is not AD. There is no LDAP built-in. It uses Open Id Connect, WS-Federation and SAML. Azure AD Domain Services might give you what you need, but you won't be able to join the App Service VMs to the domain any way.

Comment: From my understanding _Azure AD Domain Services_ can be accessed via LDAP without joining the client system to the domain (just like with using LDAP for accessing on-premise MS AD).

Comment: @juunas I also mean AAD. We have azure active directory setup synched to our on-premise domain and also a azure ad domain service.

Comment: @MichaelStröder Ok, so azure ad domain services need to have secure ldap setup and then connect this way with the need to join a domain?

Comment: IIRC you would have to pay extra bugs for AAD Domain Services. So I'd also recommend to dive into SSO mechs for web apps.

Comment: @MichaelStröder No problem. We already have domain services setup because Azure VMs need to join our domain. Trying secure LDAP setup now.

Comment: @MichaelStröder Wouldn't the web-app need to have the ldap certificate installed in order to connecto via secure ldap over the internet? Since there is no VM it is not possible to install the certificate?

Comment: I'd just try. Maybe that have their own root CA certs pre-installed somewhere. I don't know.

Comment: @MichaelStröder Just a FYI. It was not possible to import the certificate into the web-app as java needs the certificate. The java keystore is not accesible from azure web-gui and the web-app console is without admin rights.

Comment: Is it possible to specify another Java key-storefile for the web-app?

Comment: @MichaelStröder It is not possible to make changes to the filesystem :-(