# OnPremise LDAP authentication for Azure Web app

Tags: authentication, ldap, azure-web-app-service

We have developed a website which is deployed in Azure Web App. Now we need to authenticate users using on-premise LDAP. We don't want to use ADFS or Azure Active Directory Sync. Is this possible? If it's not possible, what are the best options I have?

Comment: I'm not sure whether there is a general issue with LDAPS and Azure Web App. See also: [Azure Active Directory/Ldap use inside web-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610851/azure-active-directory-ldap-use-inside-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

One of my customers is using my [Æ-DIR](https://ae-dir.com) also for Azure logins. It's based on OpenLDAP and a two-tier replication topology is used:

- provider replicas with read-write access
- consumer replicas with read-only access

They have read-only consumers deployed to Azure VMs because they would not allow incoming network connections to their on-premise network. Also you have to consider availability of your network connections from Azure to your on-premise installation.

Furthermore they installed an on-premise SAML IdP which also allows authenticating the users in Azure portal without Azure AAD having real usable passwords. The user accounts are synced to Azure AAD though.

AFAIK they do not use Azure Web App. Instead they are hosting their own web servers as Azure VMs.